# Windows 7 default programs and Python

Tags: python, windows-7, tkinter, default

I'm making photo viewing application for Windows 7 using Python 2.6. I'd like to make it so that my program automatically becomes the default photo-viewer on Windows, how would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help: [Add your program to "Default Programs" in Windows 7](http://ciantic.blogspot.com/2010/01/add-your-program-to-default-programs-in.html)